# POST to Django safely without using forms but avoiding CSRF errors

Tags: python, ios, json, django, csrf

I would like to POST data from my iOS app to my Django server — encoding it all in the URL is just impractical.  I want to do this without a form, simply sending JSON data up and getting JSON data out.  When I try, I’m running into this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)
```

For development, I’m currently getting around this by declaring my view method to be `@csrf_exempt`, but I’m worried that’s unsafe for production.  **Is it if I’m also declaring the method `@login_required`?**

Assuming it is unsafe, how can I solve this?  I understand the approach using `{% csrf_token %}` in HTML templates -- I’ve used that in other Django apps -- but again, I’m not actually using a form, nor do I wish to.  I’m simply encoding my request data in a JSON dictionary, and getting a JSON dictionary back.  Here’s the relevant part of the client side:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictWithMyData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (!data) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"NSJSONSerialization error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myServerMethodUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:timeout];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}
```

And here’s the relevant server part:

```
@login_required
def my_server_method(request):
    data = simplejson.loads(request.body)
    R = {}
    # Do stuff with the data here and generate a response with JSON data in R
    ....
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(R), content_type="application/json")
```

From what I’ve learned of the CSRF mechanism, the CSRF token is valid for the entire session.  So I thought I could make this work by:  a) upon authentication, passing the CSRF token to my iOS client, and then b) including the token when I post my data.  Here’s how I tried that.

Upon authentication in the server, I find the CSRF token with this and send it to the client:

```
session_csrf_token = django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
```

And I try to pass it back by modifying my client code above like so.  First I augment the data I send with my `session_csrf_token` (stored as `_csrfToken` on the client upon login):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictCSRF = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictWithMyData];
[dictCSRF setObject:_csrfToken forKey:@"csrfmiddlewaretoken"];
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictCSRF options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:error];
```

Then I augment the request header like so:

```
[request setValue:_csrfToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRF-Token"];
```

But it’s not working.  I get the same "CSRF token missing or incorrect" error.

**Any ideas how to get this to work?**

Comment: You should be able to use the same approach as for Ajax posts, which is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: Can you explain how this might work?  The documentation shows how to use it with jQuery in a web page, but I’m not serving up a web page.